HLS Stream Stops and Fails to Restart on iOS
I'm working on an iOS app using JWPlayer SDK to stream an HLS video. However, the stream stops and doesn't restart on both emulators and real devices. The output provides the following information:
"transportType" : "HTTP Live Stream",
"mediaType" : "HTTP Live Stream",
"name" : "MEDIA_PLAYBACK_STALL" ,
"interfaceType" : “Wifi"
Additionally, the log shows:
(16830): Media file not received in 21s
Can anyone guide me on this issue?

I think you got down-voted for not providing enough useful information (eg: this is a bad quality question, as it is currently written)... (1) Does "stream an HLS video" involve any online https:// file path? If yes, is there an .m3u8 involved? If yes, is there an actual m3u8 link to share for testing? (2) Is LocalHost involved in this HLS streaming? (3) The stream stops after playing for how many seconds? If you had an m3u8 you could check (using text reader) if the "stops" time is same as for duration of first file in the playlist. Maybe there's a problem when switching files?
